# Запуск PHP скрипта с помощью Cron

Tags: cron, php

Приветствую.

Попробовал прописать в crontab: 01 *    * * * /usr/bin/php -q /var/www/_cron.php

Но, скрипт не запускается и в syslog появляется ошибка:

```
Nov 10 11:19:01 /usr/sbin/cron[1583]: (*system*) RELOAD (/etc/crontab)
Nov 10 11:19:01 cron[1583]: Error: bad username; while reading /etc/crontab
Nov 10 11:19:01 /usr/sbin/cron[1583]: (*system*) ERROR (Syntax error, this crontab file will be ignored)
```

Answer (score 1):

Вариантов несколько. Выберите подходящий:

```
0 * * * * /usr/bin/lynx -source http://example.com/_cron.php 
0 * * * * /usr/bin/wget -O - -q -t 1 http://www.example.com/_cron.php 
0 * * * * curl -s http://example.com/_cron.php
```

Вместо *`example.com`* можно использовать *`localhost`*, если хочется.

PS. В вашем примере ещё, возможно влияет *`01`* в начале строки.